# Error: types/values length mismatchProblem when calling payable contract function with web3

Tags: web3js, infura, ethereumjs-tx

Enviroment

`Node version: v10.15.3
Web3: ^1.0.0-beta.50
Net: Ropsten`

My smart contract is a very simple payable/balance one and my goal is to contribute 0.1 ETH to raise the contract balance using web3:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

contract Demo {
 uint public balance;

 constructor() public
 {
  balance = 0;
 }

 function contribute() public payable
 {
  balance += msg.value;
 }
}
```

And Im trying to call contribute function with web3:

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
import Tx from "ethereumjs-tx";
import contractAbi from "./contractAbi";

    const web3 = new Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxx");

    const contractAdress = "xxxx";
    const my_public_key_address_1 = "yyyy";
    const privateKey1 = "vvv";

    const txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_public_key_address_1);
    const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAdress);

    const txObject = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      to: "xxx",
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(41000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("4", "gwei")),
      data: contract.methods.contribute(100000000000000000).encodeABI(),
      chainId: 3,
    };
    //
    const tx = new Tx(txObject);
    tx.sign(privateKey1)
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

    const txHash = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)
```

And Im getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Note that `100000000000000000 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: And in any case, function `contribute` does not take any input arguments, so `contract.methods.contribute(100000000000000000)` is not a valid transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contribute` doesn't take any parameters, but you're trying to pass one. You probably instead wanted to call the function with no parameters but attach ether to the transaction:

```
const txObject = {
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
  to: "xxx",
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(41000),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("4", "gwei")),

  // NOTE: Drop the parameter here:
  data: contract.methods.contribute().encodeABI(),

  chainId: 3,

  // NOTE: Add a value (in wei) here:
  value: "100000000000000000",
};
```